Missing Solutions in KKT Optimisation Problem
In the attached inequality, constrained, optimisation, problem. Looking at the specific case where $\lambda_1 = 0, \lambda_2 > 0$ that I am trying to solve, you can see that I have managed to find half of the critical points, however, the mark scheme identifies additional critical points from this case (-2,0) and (2,0) these can be seen fairly easily from inspection of the constraint. However, I am concerned that there should be a systematic way of finding them apart from just guessing values in the constraint, and I think I would have missed them.

Is my approach correct so far?
How would I have found these other critical points systematically?
Is there a better or faster way of solving this case for the 4 critical points?

Apologies for uploading hand written solutions, i have RSI from typing, and so excessive typing is problematic atm. Thanks for your understanding!

Update
Thanks to an interesting point raised by @tdm in the comments, i am also uploading the mark scheme! All thoughts welcome.


How does $(x,y) = (2,0)$ satisfy the constraint $y + \lambda_1 5 + \lambda_2 2x = 0$ if $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 > 0$?

yeah i see your point, and technically $(-2, 0)$ also seems to fail 3, and $(2,0)$ fails 4.  I think $(-2,0)$ works for 4 i believe because technically if $y = 0$ the constraint becomes $x + \lambda_1 10 + \lambda_2 8y ≤ 0$ I'm uploading the mark scheme additionally, is it an error or am i missing something. Sadly there are no professors i can contact!
